# How do i writing timing function for lightning flash in C++?

Tags: opengl, c++, physics

I need to write a horror scene with lightning flash. Unfortunately I am new to both C++ and OpenGL and I am looking for efficient way to mimic lightning timing in C++/OpenGL?

I don't need graphical implementation, just algorithmic implementation.

as such, the function should return a float representing lighting intensity and the delay of lightning flash should be random (5 seconds followed by 10 seconds then 3 seconds.. etc)

I hope I made everything clear!

Comment: Presumably you tried using a random number generator? What does your code look like so far, and where are you stuck, or how does the output of your current code differ from what you want?

Comment: I am not there yet, I will be working on this in couple of days.  I asked this question to gain information about common practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some persistent state and a frame counter passed in:

```
float lightning(lightningState* state, uint64 frame){
    if(!state->enabled) return 0.0f;
    if(frame - state->lastStart < state->flashDuration) 
         // during flash
         return 1.0f; //can also have a decreasing function here based on the difference
    if(frame - state->lastStart >= state->nextFlashDelay){
        //start of next flash
        state->lastStart = frame;
        state->nextFlashDelay = rollTimeOut(5, 20, *state->rngSeed);
        return 1.0f;
    }
    //no flash
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Frame you say? That is logical.

Comment: Thanks mate, I officially accept your post as an answer :))))